# How do I retrieve the ACCOUNTNAME from this JSON?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to figure out how to loop over JSON with jQuery and output just a certain column.

Here is my JSON response from my database pull:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ACCOUNTID","ACCOUNTNAME","ADDRESS1","ADDRESS2"],"DATA":[[1,"ZooLoo Inc","123 ELm St","Orlando"],[2,"Go Company Inc","567 ELm St","Orlando"],[3,"House Inc","4232 Main St","Orlando"]]}
```

Here is the jQuery code that I am trying to use:

```
function showResponse(data){

        $.each(data.COLUMNS, function(i, item){

            if (item == 'ACCOUNTNAME') {

                $("#alertBox").append(data.DATA + " ");

            }

        });
```

My goal is to get just the account name out of it and output it. I have been playing with variations of the loop but I cannot figure out how to tell it to just give me the account names. I just want it to output the 3 account names.

Any help with this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks reasonable enough to me... what's it not doing? http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sQH7s/

Comment: Your JSON is a little weird. You have an array of names and then another object that stores more arrays of data...is that correct? I think that's probably your problem. You should look at possibly restructuring your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other posts have already suggested, you'd probably be better off reorganizing the output a little to make better use of the JSON (i.e. item.ACCOUNTNAME instead of having to access it via array indexer).

Aepheus has it right that you don't need jQuery to do this.  However, if you are intent on using jQuery, may I suggest this solution ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edN9y/)):

```
var dataCol = -1;
$.each(data.COLUMNS, function(i, item) {
    if (item == 'ACCOUNTNAME') {
        dataCol = i;
        return false;
    }
});
if (dataCol != -1) {
    $.each(data.DATA, function(i, item){
        //item[dataCol] should be Account Name. Do what you want with it.
        //I chose to append it to a list.
        $("#alertBox").append('<li>' + item[dataCol] + '</li>');    
    }); 
} else {
    $("#alertBox").append('<li>No accounts</li>');   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I need to keep it in jQuery and this worked.

Answer (score 3):

Skip jQuery, you don't need it for this.

```
function showResponse(data){
    //if you don't know the index of account name:
    var nNameIndex = -1;
    //you may be able to replace this loop with 
    //nNameIndex = data["COLUMNS"].indexOf("ACCOUNTNAME");
    //but I'm not sure how browser compatible that is, and how compatible you need to be.
    for(var nI = 0; nI < data["COLUMNS"].length; nI++){
       if(data["COLUMNS"][nI] == "ACCOUNTNAME"){
          nNameIndex = nI;
          break;
       }
    }
    if(nNameIndex  != -1)
        for(var nI = 0; nI < data["DATA"].length; nI++){
           //data["DATA"][nI] -- this is the array of values
           alert(data["DATA"][nI][nNameIndex]);//second column of array, account name
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making your JSON look like this:

```
{"COLUMNS":
    [{
        "ACCOUNTID": 1,
        "ACCOUNTNAME": "ZooLoo Inc",
        "ADDRESS1": "123 ...",
        "ADDRESS2": "Orlando"
    },
    {
        "ACCOUNTID" 2,
        ...
    }]
}
```

Using this format would make grabbing the account name as simple as `data.COLUMNS.ACCOUNTNAME` rather than a complex series of arrays/loops.